# A logging saying "A problem has occurred and the system can't receover \n please log out and try again" error message

Tags: logging, 23.10

I recently upgraded my machine from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and the system works fine but when I start my machine, this error message occurs and I then wait for a pop-up to write the password again, I tried two solutions (which I found when searching)
I tried searching for crash reports using this command and deleting if there were any

```
ls /var/crash/
```

I also tried writing something related to the Apport program which sends crash reports,

```
sudo nano /etc/default/apport
```

and then changing `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you find the same issue, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> the following command:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

And that will change the interface of the login software it will give you a choice between lightdm and gdm3.
Then change to lightdm and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the terminal.